# remove listitem blue selection

Tags: android, listview

I added the following selector to my listview in my drawerlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Selected -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

colorPrimaryDark and colorPrimary are just color values

This work amost fine. But if i press and release an listitem on API 19 or lower, the item gets blue. How is that possible?

Comment: you mean to say when the list item is pressed and released ? 
what are your colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark

Comment: @Ramesh I added your questions to my question

Comment: I meant by any chance if they are blue colors ?

Comment: and this issue does not persist if you dont have background of list item as this selector ? if so, can you remove one by one and see which is causing the problem !! (my suspect being focussed state. just focussed without press)

Comment: Even with an empty selecter it occured, but i found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

```
 android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

This appeared to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat as a theme you should reference the colors from theme like this

```
<item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

Comment: I'm not using colors from the theme

Answer (score 0):

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

add this attribute for your listview

Comment: This could afford to have more detail added to it.